# Program crashing with 'std::out_of_range' error

Tags: c++

I am working on a wheel of fortune project for school and am running into some issues with pointers.

This is the issue I have on my program, (cmd output):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::compare: __pos (which is 1) > this->size() (which is 0)

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

The game is designed to work similarly to the wheel of fortune game.  What I'm doing at first is filtering out the 'rlstne' letters.  That works without using pointers, but I have to use a pointer.  This is my full program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(){

    std::string original_string = "THIS LINE IS THE GAME";
    std::string str1;
    std::string str2 = "RLSTNE";
    int y = 0;

    bool restart = true;

    std::string* arr_temp =  new std::string[100];
    std::string* arr_temp1 = new std::string[100];
    *arr_temp1 = str1;
    *arr_temp = str2;
do{

        std::cout << "What string?" << std::endl;
        getline(std::cin, str1);
        std::cout << str1.length() << std::endl;

    for(int x = 0; x < str1.length(); x++){

        if((arr_temp->compare(0,1, *arr_temp1, x, 1)) == 0){
            str1[x] = '_';
        }
        if((arr_temp->compare(1,1, *arr_temp1, x, 1)) == 0){
            str1[x] = '_';
        }
        if((arr_temp->compare(2,1, *arr_temp1, x, 1)) == 0){
            str1[x] = '_';
        }
        if((arr_temp->compare(3,1, *arr_temp1, x, 1)) == 0){
            str1[x] = '_';
        }   
        if((arr_temp->compare(4,1, *arr_temp1, x, 1)) == 0){
            str1[x] = '_';
        }
        if((arr_temp->compare(5,1, *arr_temp1, x, 1)) == 0){
            str1[x] = '_';
        }
}
*arr_temp1 = str1;
std::cout << *arr_temp1 <<std::endl;
Sleep(1000);
}while(restart);
}
```

I think this is where my program goes wrong:

```
std::string str1;
std::string str2 = "RLSTNE";
```

str1 is not initialized to any value, so the compiler sees it as 0 length, but I've tried initializing it to different values.  Such as the string value of the original_string.

This is the code:

```
std::string str1 = "THIS LINE IS THE GAME";
std::string str2 = "RLSTNE";
```

This is the output:

```
What string?
THIS LINE IS THE GAME
21
_HI_ _I__ I_ _H_ GAM_
```

But when I try to add more than the original value which is 21, I get this problem:

```
What string?
THIS LINE IS THE GAMEEEE
24
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::compare: __pos (which is 22) > this->size() (which is 21)
```

So my question is:  What is the compiler printing out? What value is 22, what value is 21?  What does this->size mean?  what does __pos mean?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you need 200 different `std::string`s for?

Comment: On the first iteration of the loop, `*arr_temp1` is an empty string. On every iteration of the loop, `*arr_temp1 != str1` so the length check in the loop is suspect.

Comment: That's the size of the dynamic string array.  It won't allow me to compile unless I give it a size.  Or shoot, that must be the uh, total number of strings huh?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Its pointing to str1, even if I have a string in it, I get an error that is relative to the size of the initialized string.  I'm comparing two strings.  arr_temp1 and arr_temp inside of those if statements

Comment: There is no pointer to `str1` anywhere in your code.

Comment: What does *arr_temp1 = str1 do?

Comment: It copies the value of `str1` into `*arr_temp1`, also known as `arr_temp1[0]`

Comment: It seems you could use [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Your program is not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Also, uses a debugger. It help a lot to trace a program line by line to learn what it does.

Comment: Why do textbooks and colleges insist on teaching students to use deprecated headers? If your instructor is telling you to use string.h and time.h rather than <string> and <ctime>, I'd drop the class based on that alone.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a high school course.

Comment: Totally unrelated: When I was a kid  I read a comic and story anthology my mom would bring home from work. Huge portions of the book always seemed to be written by a "Jovial Bob Stine". I was 40 before I found out he was the R L Stine scaring the crap out of the kids.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string* arr_temp =  new std::string[100];
std::string* arr_temp1 = new std::string[100];
```

Each of these is a pointer to an array of 100 strings. Also, because you use `new`, you need `delete` somewhere in your code, otherwise you've got a memory leak. But you don't seem to need dynamic memory. So the fixed version would be

```
std::string* arr_temp;
std::string* arr_temp1;
```

Your big for loop can be simplified with a nested loop, but that's not really the focus here. As for your error - the exception `std::out_of_range` means you went past the limits of your array. The code causing it is as follows:

```
std::string str1 = "THIS LINE IS THE GAME"; //makes a new string
*arr_temp1 = str1; //dereferences arr_temp1 and sets arr_temp1[0] to whatever str1 currently is
```

So you've set `arr_temp1[0] = "THIS LINE IS THE GAME"` (length of 21). Then you set `str1 = "THIS LINE IS THE GAMEEEE"` (length of 24). Your loop tries to access the first 24 characters of arr_temp1[0]. But that won't work - it has a length of 21. So as soon as it gets to the 22nd character, it throws you an `std::out_of_range` error.

In summary, most of this isn't doing what you think it is. I recommend reading up on pointers a bit and start from scratch.

Comment: There is another error with using a y value for the str.compare(y, 1, str2, x, 1). So I just hard coded it for now.  It wasn't an error, it just crashed.